# Automatically mounting drives in error

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, thinkcentre

A Lenovo ThinkCentre Windows 7 PC is automatically creating mounted drives, using the next available drive letter, eg: L etc & slowing the computer down.

Comment: How does that slow the computer down? That operation should be almost instantaneous, and you aren't plugging in/unplugging drives al day...

Comment: What is the scenario of drive letter changed? USB drives ?

Answer (score 0):

disable automount drives:

```
mountvol /N
```

enable automount drives:

```
mountvol /E
```

check disk warring, error, event:

```
powershell Get-Eventlog system -Source Disk
```